# how to pop right most(lowest value) item from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':1}
```

So I want to pop (or any other method, that remove and return) `'d'` because it is the lowest
Value and the right most item (in case 2 keys have the same value), values will always be ints.

I tried:

```
dic.popItem()
```

But I'm just getting a random item back, any ideas?

Also tried:

```
temp = min(dic.values)
del dic[temp]
```

But again, it's not working!

Comment: The rightmost-ness of `d` is lost as soon as it is inserted into the dictionar. The best you can do is remove _one of_ the lowest-value entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as the right-most item, because dictionaries are unordered.

You can delete *one* of the lowest-value items like this:

```
item = min(dic, key=dic.get)
del dic[item]
```

Comment: `item = min(dic, key=dic.__getitem__)` might be a touch faster

Comment: `key=dic.get` even better

Comment: Thanks for that @wim, that's really nice. Updated.

Comment: how about `dic.pop(min(dic, key=dic.get))`

Comment: If i am using Counter(), do i have a better way to do it?

Comment: Counter just works the same way as a dictionary for item access and deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ordereddict to get a consistent result.

See this post:

[Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)